# How to design content for sub-pages

Tags: nodes

Just looking for more experienced drupal developers to steer me in the right direction, it's kind of a basic question:

What is the best way to design the content of the pages, as in, I have the page templates done (front/sub-pages), now I have a bunch of informational sub-pages that I have to design the content for. I thought I could just populate them using the wysiwyg editor, but starting to realize that has limitations. So what's the protocol?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds)

Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views, comments, user data etc.

This is a great [tutorial](http://zugec.com/blog/76-display-suite-part-1-layouts-and-styles) to understand how Display Suite works.

Hope this answer may help you.

Comment: Great, definitely worth exploring more. There's a million ways to do things in Drupal, which sometimes results in too many options!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly: change your input type to "Full HTML". Then write your own HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suppose what I need is an editor with more HTML options in it. Full HTML still adds tags to the content area. I actually set it on PHP code and that creates a clean output.